# Manually specify AWS access key

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

Is it possible to create an AWS access key where you specify the key and secret? I need to recreate one that got deleted when a user got deleted if possible for an S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You will need to generate a new set of keys and replace them.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html#Using_CreateAccessKey